# Como usar múltiples dataSources en Spring JDBC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbc-template

Tengo agregados a mi ***application.yml*** multiples ***dataSources*** de esta manera

```
spring:
  main:
 allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: crge-ws-api-rest
  profiles:
    active: dev
  datasource:
    crge:
      driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      url: jdbc:sqlserver://servidor1.com:1433;databaseName=bd-example-1
      username: user@servidor1
      password: Password1
      jdbcUrl: ${spring.datasource.crge.url}
    concesio:
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
      url: jdbc:sqlserver://servidor2.com:1521;databaseName=bd-example-2
      username: user
      password: Password2
      jdbcUrl: ${spring.datasource.concesio.url}
    cored:
      driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
      url: jdbc:sqlserver://servidor2.com:1521;databaseName=bd-example-3
      username: user
      password: Password2
      jdbcUrl: ${spring.datasource.cored.url}
```

y en mi archivo ***application.java*** creo los respectivos ***Beans*** de la siguiente forma

```
package gob.ips.crge.ws.api.rest.config;

import com.beust.jcommander.JCommander;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "gob.ips.crge.ws.api.rest.*")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PropertiesConfig.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        JCommander.newBuilder().addObject(app).build().parse(args);
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.crge")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JdbcTemplate JdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.concesio")
    public DataSource concesioDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate ConcesioJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(concesioDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.cored")
    public DataSource coredDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate CoredJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(coredDataSource());
    }

}
```

En ese archivo, solo me funciona el ***Bean*** declarado como `@Primary`, utilizando en los repositorios el codigo de esta manera

```
@Repository
public class TipoInstitucionDAOImpl extends BaseDAO implements TipoInstitucionDAO {

    @Autowired
    public TipoInstitucionDAOImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        super.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    public List<TipoInstitucion> getTipoInstituciones() throws DAOException {
        
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = super.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new DAOException(Utils.reemplazarParametrosMsg(MSG_ERROR_AL_CONSULTAR_TIPO_INSTS),ex);
        } finally {
            SQLServerUtils.closeAll(connection, cs, rs, metodo);
        }
    }
}
```

¿Como hago para inyectar los demas ***Beans*** y poder hacer consultas a esas bases de datos?

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Si puedo luego pondré una respuesta, pero aquí tienes información en inglés: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que nombrar los beans de esta manera

```
@Bean(name = "concesio")
public JdbcTemplate ConcesioJdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(concesioDataSource());
}
```

y para usar otro bean que no sea el que tiene la anotacion `@primary` tienes que inyectarlos asi:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("concesio")
JdbcTemplate concesioJdbcTemplate;
```